# icon notification in statusbar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I use `flutter_local_notification` for manage fcm notification in flutter.
for show icon in `StatusBar`, add logo png file in drawable and use it.

my image is white, when `StatusBar` is white, icon not appears.
another apps like whatsapp, notification icon color changed based `Appbar` color.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try generate the icon for your notification using this link https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html then make sure you has defined the icon in your initializatuon, example for Android:

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_firebase_notification');
```

and add this code inside the `application tag` in `AndroidManifext.xml` file.

```
<!-- Add custom icon to the notifications -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_firebase_notification" />
```

and don't forget to put the icon that you generated before to `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/` folder. i tried this before, and it worked like a charm in my case.

Comment: thanks, solved my problem with this link

Answer (score 3):

Attention! `icon background` must be `transparent` to be shown as notification icon.